# Why is my redirect in .htaccess not masked

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-7

In my Drupal 7 site I have added this row in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^mypath/?$ /sites/default/files/myfolder/ [R=302,L]
```

Which works fine, but I was expecting the URL to be masked, that `mypath` would still show in the URL and not `/sites/default/files/myfolder/`

How can I achieve the masking that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the `R` redirection flag it tells the browser to change URL in address bar.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^mypath/?$ /sites/default/files/myfolder/ [L]
```